# R count difference in days based on column value

Tags: r, date, datetime

I'm trying to count the difference in dates from a single column, based on another columns value.

This is the result I'm looking for

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
library('dplyr')
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
                Date = c('1/1/2020', '1/3/2020','1/1/2020','1/7/2020','1/6/2020','1/5/2020'))

df %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format='%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(DIFF = Date - lag(Date))
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, same results as my comments above.

Comment: my code is different than above solution, this is getting the difference between two consecutive day and not difference between current and the first one

Comment: it would be better to update your example with more rows

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `dplyr` and `lubridate` (needed to make the dates behave when subtracting). It looks like you want the calculation to determine the number of days between the dates in a group by ID and the earliest date for that ID.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Diff = Date - min(Date))
```

If you want to have `NA` instead of 0, you can do the following:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Diff = if_else(Date == min(Date), NA_integer_, Date - min(Date))
```

Comment: I tried this, but it only counts from the first column. I need it to count by ID, and repeat several time. For example ID 1 can have 4 days, I need the difference from one date to the next, not first date to each of the following.